# LINQ: Gridview is updating every row with same values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, gridview

I want to run some methods while updating a gridview without using the normal Update command. And I believe I can use RowUpdating to do it, however.

```
 protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;

        TextBox txtID = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox13");
        TextBox txtDate1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDate1");
        TextBox txtDate2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDate2");
        Label duration = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label13");
        Label diff = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label14");
        Label remainder = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label15");
        Label expiry = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label17");
        DropDownList ddlName = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlName");
        DropDownList ddlType = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlType");
        DropDownList ddlLocation = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlLocation");
        DropDownList ddlFee = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlFee");

         //dc.updateArchive(Variables goes here);
         GridView2.DataBind();
         GridView2.EditIndex = -1;  }
```

After messing around I was able to read the values from the selected row (The row that I clicked Edit on) but what happens here is that every row is being updated with same values that I entered on the row that was on Edit mode (Selected?).

I need to grab the datakey of the row that is being edited. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var key=GridView2.DataKeys[selectedRowIndex].Value;
```

But make sure you have `datakeynames` in your `gridview`.

```
datakeynames="LocationID"
//name of you actual primary key field in you select data source.
```